# Log4j recognized logj4.debug, but not respecting log4j.properties setting?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am running a testcase from within Intellij with the following jvm parameters

```
-Xmx2512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dlog4j.properties=log4j.mllib.properties -Dlog4j.debug
```

The interesting thing is that the

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

property IS being respected, but the

```
-Dlog4j.properties is not.
```

The evidence?  In the output log file we see:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@560dd7a7.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@560dd7a7 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@560dd7a7.
log4j: Using URL [file:/shared/pic/mllib/target/scala-2.10/test-classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/shared/pic/mllib/target/scala-2.10/test-classes/log4j.properties
..
```

So we DO see the verbose (Debugging  level) on log4j processing - as represented by -Dlog4j.debug.  But the -Dlog4j.properties was not respected.

Comment: Which log4j version are you running? log4j 1.2 or log4j 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j.mllib.properties` instead.